# php GearmanClient timeout

Tags: php, gearman

I'm using the gearman pecl extension in php, and want to have a timeout for a function call.
Two use cases: (1) no running workers, (2) worker takes too long to complete

If everything is running, the call is very fast, and I want to avoid having an overhead for this timeout.

Code I currently use:

```
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$client->do('nonexistingfunction');
```

Comment: I have a related but slightly more complex use case, so have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036819/get-response-from-multiple-jobs-in-gearman-but-abort-after-a-timeout/49049263

Answer (score 0):

Just call [GearmanClient::setTimeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.settimeout.php) method with number of milliseconds to wait:

```
$client = new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();
$client->setTimeout(5000);
```

Comment: I think this the timeout for I/O communication with the gearman deamon and won't help with my issue.