# Get response from multiple jobs in Gearman, but abort after a timeout

Tags: php, gearman

**In a nutshell**: I want to have an overall timeout for a call to `runTasks()` in a Gearman client.

I feel like I can't be the first person to want this, but I can't find an example of how to put it together.

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. In a PHP script, use the Gearman client to start a series of jobs in parallel
2. Each job will produce some search results, which the PHP script will need to process
3. Some of the jobs may take some time to run, but I don't want to wait for the slowest. Instead, after N milliseconds, I want to process the results from all of the jobs that have completed, and abort or ignore those that haven't.

Requirements 1 and 2 are simple enough using the PHP GearmanClient's [addTask()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addtask.php) and [runTasks()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.runtasks.php) methods, but this blocks until *all* the submitted jobs are completed, so doesn't meet requirement 3.

Here are some approaches I've tried so far:

- The timeout set with [setTimeout()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.settimeout.php) measures the time the connection has been *idle*, which isn't what I'm interested in.
- Using background jobs or tasks, there doesn't seem to be any way of retrieving the data returned by the worker. There are several questions already covering this: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982450/gearman-sending-data-from-a-background-worker-to-the-client) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615941/gearman-is-there-still-no-way-to-retrieve-custom-data-from-a-background-worker)
- The custom polling loop in the example for [addTaskStatus()](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addtaskstatus.php) is almost what I need, but it uses background jobs, so again can't see any results. It also includes the vague comment "a better method would be to use event callbacks", without explaining what callbacks it means, or which part of the example they'd replace.
- The client options include a GEARMAN_CLIENT_NON_BLOCKING mode, but I don't understand how to use this, and if a non-blocking `runTasks()` is any different from using `setTaskBackground()` instead of `setTask()`.

I've seen suggestions that return communication could just use a different mechanism, like a shared data store, but in that case, I might as well ditch Gearman and build a custom solution with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a workable solution, although I'd still be interested in alternatives.

The key is that calling `runTasks()` again after an I/O timeout continues to wait for the previous synchronous tasks, so you can build a polling loop out of these parts:

- Synchronous, parallel, tasks set up with `addTask()`.
- A completion callback set with `setCompleteCallback()` which tracks which tasks have finished and how many are still pending.
- A low I/O timeout set with `setTimeout()` which acts as your polling frequency.
- Repeated calls to `runTasks()` in a loop, exiting when either all tasks are done, or an overall timeout is reached. This could also have more complex exit conditions, like "after N seconds, or at least X results", etc.

The big downside is that the timeouts issue a PHP Warning, so you have to squash that with a custom error handler or the `@` operator.

Here's a fully tested example:

```
// How long should we wait each time around the polling loop if nothing happens
define('LOOP_WAIT_MS', 100);
// How long in total should we wait for responses before giving up
define('TOTAL_TIMEOUT_MS', 5000);

$client= new GearmanClient();
$client->addServer();

// This will fire as each job completes.
// In real code, this would save the data for later processing,
// as well as tracking which jobs were completed, tracked here with a simple counter.
$client->setCompleteCallback(function(GearmanTask $task) use (&$pending) {
        $pending--;
        echo "Complete!\n";
        echo $task->data();
});

// This array can be used to track the tasks created. This example just counts them.
$tasks = [];
// Sample tasks; the workers sleep for specified number of seconds before returning some data.
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');
$tasks[] = $client->addTask('wait', '2');

$pending = count($tasks);

// This is the key polling loop; runTasks() here acts as "wait for a notification from the server"
$client->setTimeout(LOOP_WAIT_MS);
$start = microtime(true);
do {
        // This will abort with a PHP Warning if no data is received in LOOP_WAIT_MS milliseconds
        // We ignore the warning, and try again, unless we've reached our overall time limit
        @$client->runTasks();
} while (
        // Exit the loop once we run out of time
        microtime(true) - $start < TOTAL_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000
        // Additional loop exit if all tasks have been completed
        // This counter is decremented in the complete callback
        && $pending > 0
);

echo "Finished with $pending tasks unprocessed.\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds like what [CAN_DO_TIMEOUT](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/blob/e2d76cf631414964decc2f22006a666e1c0e2424/PROTOCOL#L327-L335) was created for:

> CAN_DO_TIMEOUT
>
> ```
>  Same as CAN_DO, but with a timeout value on how long the job
>  is allowed to run. After the timeout value, the job server will
>  mark the job as failed and notify any listening clients.
>
>  Arguments:
>  - NULL byte terminated Function name.
>  - Timeout value.
> ```

So for any (Worker,Function) tuple you can define a maximum time the Worker will process a Job, otherwise it'll be discarded.

Unfortunately there appears to be a [bug](https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/issues/58) in the C Server where the timeout is hard-coded at 1000 seconds.

One workaround is if you're able to implement your timeout logic outside of gearman. For example, if you're using curl, soap, sockets, etc., one can often achieve the desired effect by tweaking those settings.

Comment: This doesn't quite meet my use case unfortunately, as it defines the timeout at the *worker* end, rather than at the *client*. That has a couple of consequences: firstly, the timeout has to be pre-agreed, the server can't configure it; more importantly, the timer only starts when the job is given to a particular worker (since different workers might have different timeouts), so if the workers are all busy, there will be extra time on top of the timeout while waiting for one to become ready.

Comment: @IMSoP - Can you elaborate on your Worker/Function configuration (if even using fictitious names)? I still believe this solution is what you're looking for since it mirrors the use-case I outlined in https://github.com/wcgallego/pecl-gearman/issues/58#issuecomment-381376475 which posits making N API requests in parallel that runTasks() can/should only block based on a maximum time (in ms - and yes it's defined on the worker side but that's OK b/c that's where the timing occurs), and failing all Jobs that did not complete within that time.

Comment: Indeed, the timer only starts when the Job is given to a Worker, and is expected. Workers must be available for Blocking Tasks to commence. An alternative would be to employ the method I described above but instead add your Tasks as _background_ (non-blocking) which would allow you to implement your own timing client side while still getting the benefit of the worker-timeout-the-discard functionality.

Comment: My use case is indeed very similar to the one you describe: polling multiple APIs, and returning as much as possible in a fixed time. But the total time for the aggregation needs to be fixed at the *aggregating* end. Imagine you set a timeout of 2 secs, get a result after 10ms from one API, and have all the other jobs stuck in a queue for 30 seconds; with a worker-side timeout, the entire aggregation will wait 32 seconds before timing out, instead of 2 seconds! Timeout at the worker end can be handled by just timing out the I/O of the API requests themselves, independent of Gearman.

Comment: As for background jobs, I covered that in my question: if you set the job to be non-blocking, it disconnects completely from the Client, and you have no way to retrieve any results (without manually implementing a return message of some sort). At that point, Gearman is just acting as a one-way message queue; which is fine as it goes, but then I'd rather use RabbitMQ for its powerful routing and extensible configuration.

Comment: In other words, on the client end, I don't care *why* a job has failed to complete in time. It might be because the remote API was slow, because post-processing was slow, or just because no worker was available to handle it. It might actually be that all the workers capable of handling that task have crashed, so the job will *never* be picked up! In all cases, I want to stop waiting after a certain time has elapsed *since the client submitted the job*.